# Radio Button Text Area and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m having a problem with my HTML, CSS & Javascript code.

Here’s the setup:

- The combination of radio buttons and a checkbox change the add-to-cart button with URLs.
- There are 5 radio buttons and 1 checkbox, so I have 10 add-to-cart buttons in total.
- Only 1 add-to-cart button is shown and others are hidden.

I added a function to change the radio button by clicking on the text area in addition to the radio button itself.

- When I click on the radio button itself, add-to-cart button is updated.
- When I click in the text area, radio button changes, but the add-to-cart button stays stuck.

I believe it has something to do with JavaScript, but I can’t figure it out.

I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you for your sharing your wisdom.

```js
// Javascript
var radioSelector = 'input[name="radio"]';
var checkboxSelector = 'input[name="checkbox"]';
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(radioSelector  +', '+ checkboxSelector).change(setActiveLinks);
   
   // call it on load
   setActiveLinks();
});

function setActiveLinks() {
   var radioValue = $(radioSelector +':checked').val();
   var isChecked = $(checkboxSelector).prop("checked");

   // first dis-active links
   $('.my-toggle-links > button').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('hidden d-none');

   // second active
   var activeSelector = '.my-toggle-links[data-radio="'+ radioValue +'"][data-checked="'+ isChecked +'"]';
   $(activeSelector + ', ' + activeSelector +' > button').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('hidden d-none');
}

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".hf").click(function(){          

        $('input[type=radio]', this).prop("checked",true);

    });
});
```

```css
<style>
/* CSS */
.mainf{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.hidden, .d-none { display: none; }
#ctable{
 text-align:left;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    padding: 15px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
th{
border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
td{
 padding: 4px;
}

.flex{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items:center
}

#cbox{
background-color: #FCF8E3;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-style: dashed;
}
.mainc{
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
}
.flex{
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items:center
}
#checkboxi{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
   transform: scale(1.5);
   /* margin-bottom: 15px;*/
}
#chead{
    color: #3bbb64;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.pro{
 color: #FF3C00;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#cbox p{
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.my-toggle-links{
 display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3bbb64;
 margin-top: 29px;
}
.my-toggle-links button{
     width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
   border: 2px solid #3bbb64;
    padding: 11px;
   font-weight: BOLD;
    font-size: 24px;
 cursor:pointer !important;
}
.md-light{
    font-size: 20px;
}
.my-toggle-links:hover{
    background-color: #4ad576;
}
.my-toggle-links button:hover{
 border: 2px solid #4ad576;
  
}
.spayment{
text-align: center;
    color: #B5B6BB;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}
.hf{
cursor:pointer}
.hf td input[type="radio"]{
    transform: scale(1.3);
     margin-right: 16px;

}

.highlited{
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 8px 1px #b2afaf
}
.highlited td{
    background-color: #FDF107;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.mp{
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 7px;}
.mpt{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 38px;
} 
</style>
```

```html
<!--Google Material Icon-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div>
 <table id="ctable" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
  <th>Qty</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  
   </tr>
  <tr class="hf">
   <td><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1"> 1x Cat Paw Necklace (Save 50%) $9.98</label> </td>
   <td>$9.98 +<br /> FREE S&H </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hf">
   <td><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2"> 2x Cat Paw Necklaces (Save 50%) $19.96</label></td>
   <td>$19.96 +<br /> FREE S&H </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hf highlited">
   <td style="border-right: 0px;">
    
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio3" checked> <span class="mp">Most Popular</span><br /><span class="mpt"> 3x Cat Paw Necklaces (Save 55%) $26.97 </span></label>
   </td>
   
   <td style="border-left: 0px;">$26.97 +<br /> FREE S&H </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hf">
   <td><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio4"> 5x Cat Paw Necklaces (Save 65%) $34.95</label></td>
   <td> $34.95 +<br /> FREE S&H </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hf">
   <td><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio5"> 7x Cat Paw Necklaces (Save 75%) $41.93 </label></td>
   <td> $41.93 +<br /> FREE S&H </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

<!-- Checkbox_Unchecked by default -->
<div id="cbox">
 <div class="mainc">
   <div class="flex">
        <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px;color:red">forward</i>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxi" name="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox" id="ctext">
   <span id="chead">Yes, Give Me The Cat Library Too!</span>
   
  </label>
   </div>
 </div>
 <p><span class="pro">ONE TIME OFFER - ONLY $4.95</span>: Want instant access to the new Digital Cat Library that helps you have a healthy and happy cat? ***Click YES to add this to your order now for just a single payment of $4.95! (This offer is not available at ANY other time or place)</p>
</div>


<!-- Button with URLs_Radio 3 & Unchecked by default -->
  <div>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url1' data-radio="radio1" data-checked="false"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url2' data-radio="radio2" data-checked="false"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url3' data-radio="radio3" data-checked="false"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url4' data-radio="radio4" data-checked="false"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url5' data-radio="radio5" data-checked="false"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url6' data-radio="radio1" data-checked="true"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url7' data-radio="radio2" data-checked="true"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url8' data-radio="radio3" data-checked="true"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url9' data-radio="radio4" data-checked="true"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url10' data-radio="radio5" data-checked="true"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART</button></a>
</div>
<div class="spayment">
 * 100% Secure & Safe Payments *
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding `.change();` after `.prop("checked",true)` it works well. But all in all, this code absolutly needs refactor.

```js
// Javascript
var radioSelector = 'input[name="radio"]';
var checkboxSelector = 'input[name="checkbox"]';
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(radioSelector  +', '+ checkboxSelector).change(setActiveLinks);
   
   // call it on load
   setActiveLinks();
});

function setActiveLinks(e) {
   console.log(e);
   var radioValue = $(radioSelector +':checked').val();
   var isChecked = $(checkboxSelector).prop("checked");

   // first dis-active links
   $('.my-toggle-links > button').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('hidden d-none');

   // second active
   var activeSelector = '.my-toggle-links[data-radio="'+ radioValue +'"][data-checked="'+ isChecked +'"]';
   $(activeSelector + ', ' + activeSelector +' > button').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('hidden d-none');
}

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".hf").click(function(){          

        $('input[type=radio]', this).prop("checked",true).change();

    });
});
```

```css
<style>
/* CSS */
.mainf{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.hidden, .d-none { display: none; }
#ctable{
 text-align:left;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    padding: 15px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
th{
border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
td{
 padding: 4px;
}

.flex{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items:center
}

#cbox{
background-color: #FCF8E3;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-style: dashed;
}
.mainc{
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
}
.flex{
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items:center
}
#checkboxi{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
   transform: scale(1.5);
   /* margin-bottom: 15px;*/
}
#chead{
    color: #3bbb64;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.pro{
 color: #FF3C00;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#cbox p{
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.my-toggle-links{
 display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3bbb64;
 margin-top: 29px;
}
.my-toggle-links button{
     width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
   border: 2px solid #3bbb64;
    padding: 11px;
   font-weight: BOLD;
    font-size: 24px;
 cursor:pointer !important;
}
.md-light{
    font-size: 20px;
}
.my-toggle-links:hover{
    background-color: #4ad576;
}
.my-toggle-links button:hover{
 border: 2px solid #4ad576;
  
}
.spayment{
text-align: center;
    color: #B5B6BB;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}
.hf{
cursor:pointer}
.hf td input[type="radio"]{
    transform: scale(1.3);
     margin-right: 16px;

}

.highlited{
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 8px 1px #b2afaf
}
.highlited td{
    background-color: #FDF107;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.mp{
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 7px;}
.mpt{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 38px;
} 
</style>
```

```html
<!--Google Material Icon-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div>
 <table id="ctable" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
  <th>Qty</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  
   </tr>
  <tr class="hf">
   <td><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1"> 1x Cat Paw Necklace (Save 50%) $9.98</label> </td>
   <td>$9.98 +<br /> FREE S&H </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hf">
   <td><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2"> 2x Cat Paw Necklaces (Save 50%) $19.96</label></td>
   <td>$19.96 +<br /> FREE S&H </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hf highlited">
   <td style="border-right: 0px;">
    
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio3" checked> <span class="mp">Most Popular</span><br /><span class="mpt"> 3x Cat Paw Necklaces (Save 55%) $26.97 </span></label>
   </td>
   
   <td style="border-left: 0px;">$26.97 +<br /> FREE S&H </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hf">
   <td><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio4"> 5x Cat Paw Necklaces (Save 65%) $34.95</label></td>
   <td> $34.95 +<br /> FREE S&H </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hf">
   <td><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio5"> 7x Cat Paw Necklaces (Save 75%) $41.93 </label></td>
   <td> $41.93 +<br /> FREE S&H </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

<!-- Checkbox_Unchecked by default -->
<div id="cbox">
 <div class="mainc">
   <div class="flex">
        <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px;color:red">forward</i>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxi" name="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox" id="ctext">
   <span id="chead">Yes, Give Me The Cat Library Too!</span>
   
  </label>
   </div>
 </div>
 <p><span class="pro">ONE TIME OFFER - ONLY $4.95</span>: Want instant access to the new Digital Cat Library that helps you have a healthy and happy cat? ***Click YES to add this to your order now for just a single payment of $4.95! (This offer is not available at ANY other time or place)</p>
</div>


<!-- Button with URLs_Radio 3 & Unchecked by default -->
  <div>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url1' data-radio="radio1" data-checked="false"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART 1</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url2' data-radio="radio2" data-checked="false"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART 2</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url3' data-radio="radio3" data-checked="false"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART 3</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url4' data-radio="radio4" data-checked="false"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART 4</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url5' data-radio="radio5" data-checked="false"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART 5</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url6' data-radio="radio1" data-checked="true"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART 6</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url7' data-radio="radio2" data-checked="true"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART 7</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url8' data-radio="radio3" data-checked="true"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART 8</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url9' data-radio="radio4" data-checked="true"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART 9</button></a>
 <a class="my-toggle-links" href='https://www.mystore.myshopify.com/url10' data-radio="radio5" data-checked="true"><button><i class="material-icons md-light"style="font-size:30px;vertical-align: text-bottom;">add_shopping_cart</i>  ADD TO CART 10</button></a>
</div>
<div class="spayment">
 * 100% Secure & Safe Payments *
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I really appreciate it. :)

Your advice on adding .change(); seems to be working in JSFiddles.

You are right that this code needs a refactor, but I’m not at the level of seeing how I can improve it.

I’ve been studying Javascript, but I had to get help in Stackoverflow to come up with with this Javascript.

Comment: Well, many this could be different in this code, for example, there is no need to many buttons for add to cart one of them can solve the problem, and you can fit rid of the add and remove many classes, also, with the decidedly more comfortable way you can do this Project. By the way, because you have just started to work with Javascript, it is usual.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to share your wisdom. I really appreciate it. Yes, it's a challenge to cross the gap between the tutorials and real life codes.